# Bash variables and types

Tags: bash, wildcards, string

I'm making a script that validate an IP address. I do this:

```
read pool
checkIp()
{
    local  ip=$1
    local  stat=1

    if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
        OIFS=$IFS
        IFS='.'
        ip=($ip)
        IFS=$OIFS
        [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]
        stat=$?

    fi
    return $stat
}

checkIp $pool
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "valid"
    else
        echo "invalid"
fi
```

The problem is that now the requirement is to valid that from the 2nd octet the input can contain the wildcard "*" (i think is better to use CIDR notation but is not the case), and now i can't use `-le` because if there is not a number, it fails.

I'd tried some forms but all conversions fails.

Comment: Not really into network addressing. Is “1.2.*.4” valid ([my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63094) allows it), or as soon a “*” is encountered the remaining pieces have to also be “*”s?

Comment: The remaining spaces should be "*"...

Comment: Note that allowing `010.010.010.010` could cause confusion as most applications and library functions (gethostbyname, inet_addr...) consider it the same as `8.8.8.8` while some other the same as `10.10.10.10` (inet_pton).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little additional rewrite. (As you use Bash-specific regular expression, just populate the `BASH_REMATCH` array instead of manipulating a word splitting.)

```
checkIp()
{
  local ip="$1"

  if [[ "$ip" =~ ^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3}|\*)\.([0-9]{1,3}|\*)\.([0-9]{1,3}|\*)$ ]]; then
    for ((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do
      [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[i]}" == '*' || "${BASH_REMATCH[i]}" -le 255 ]] || return 1
    done

    return 0
  fi

  return 1
}
```

**Update** according to [owner's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63091/bash-variables-and-types/63104#comment90118_63091) to disallow numbers after “*”:

```
checkIp()
{
  local ip="$1"
  local asterisk=''

  if [[ "$ip" =~ ^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3}|\*)\.([0-9]{1,3}|\*)\.([0-9]{1,3}|\*)$ ]]; then
    for ((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do
      [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[i]}" == '*' || ( ! "$asterisk" && "${BASH_REMATCH[i]}" -le 255 ) ]] || return 1
      [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[i]}" == '*' ]] && asterisk='1'
    done

    return 0
  fi

  return 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the record, with zsh, you could write it:

```
[[ $ip = <0-255>.(<0-255>|"*").(<0-255>|"*").(<0-255>|"*") ]]
```

Note that it allows `000001.0000255.*.0`, but not `0377.1.1.1` (even though `0377` as taken as an octal number is within range), because it only considers decimal numbers.